# Remove 'urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302:' from urlReq(url)

Tags: python, url, cookies, beautifulsoup, urllib

Hey guys what's up? :) 
I'm trying to scrape a website with some url parameters.
If I use **url1, url2, url3** it **WORKS** properly and it prints me the regular output I want (html) ->

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as urlReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# create urls
url1 = 'https://en.titolo.ch/sale'
url2 = 'https://en.titolo.ch/sale?limit=108'
url3 = 'https://en.titolo.ch/sale?category_styles=29838_21212'
url4 = 'https://en.titolo.ch/sale?category_styles=31066&limit=108'

# opening up connection on each url, grabbing the page
uClient = urlReq(url4)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# parsing the downloaded html
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# print the html
print(page_soup.body.prettify())
```

-> BUT when I try **"url4"** `url4 = 'https://en.titolo.ch/sale?category_styles=31066&limit=108'` It gives me the Error below. What am I doing wrong? 
- Maybe it has something to do with cookies? -> But why does it work on the other urls...
- Maybe they are just blocking the scrape attempt?
- How can I avoid this error with using **multiple Parameters in the URL**?

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Moved Temporarily
```

Thanks for the help in advance!
Cheers
Alan

**What I have already tried**:
I tried the requests lib

```
import requests

url = 'https://en.titolo.ch/sale?category_styles=31066&limit=108'
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
print(html)

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /sale
on this server.</p>
</body></html>

[Finished in 0.375s]
```

**Full Error Message from urllib request:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jedi\Documents\non\of\your\business\smile\stackoverflow_question", line 12, in <module>
    uClient = urlReq(url4)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\jedi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 745, in http_error_302
    self.inf_msg + msg, headers, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Moved Temporarily
[Finished in 2.82s]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use `requests` package and add in the user agent in the headers, it looks like it's getting `200` response for all 4 of those links. So try adding in the user agent headers:

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'}

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# create urls
url1 = 'https://en.titolo.ch/sale'
url2 = 'https://en.titolo.ch/sale?limit=108'
url3 = 'https://en.titolo.ch/sale?category_styles=29838_21212'
url4 = 'https://en.titolo.ch/sale?category_styles=31066&limit=108'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'}

url_list = [url1, url2, url3, url4]

for url in url_list:
# opening up connection on each url, grabbing the page
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print (response.status_code)
```

**Output:**

```
200
200
200
200
```

So:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://en.titolo.ch/sale?category_styles=31066&limit=108'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
html = r.text
print(html)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! It works properly. I am not familiar with http so this helped me very much! Have a nice week. :D