# Download zip file from url that redirects in Python

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, zip

I have this code:

```
import shutil
import urllib.request
import zipfile

url = "http://wwww.some-file.com/my-file.zip"
file_name = url.split('/')[-1]

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_name, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zf:
        zf.extractall()
```

When trying the code I receive the following error:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found
```

I have been trying to combine solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55414610/remove-urllib-error-httperror-http-error-302-from-urlrequrl) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419162/download-returned-zip-file-from-url) with no luck. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have used this solution for my project when I needed to download .gz files, maybe it will work for you.

```
from urllib.request import Request as urllibRequest

request = urllibRequest(url)
with open(file_name, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(urlopen(request).read())
```

Comment: Thanks. With that method I receive the same error I describe in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think the remote server can cause this issue. The server expects user headers and if there are no headers, then cause a redirect. As you mentioned, it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55414610/remove-urllib-error-httperror-http-error-302-from-urlrequrl)


Try to add user headers